# Nested function call with array default parameter

Tags: php

What I want to achieve: when test() is called without any argument, I want that nested() function is called with default arguments.

**UPD:** Requirements:

- no copy-pasting default argument value from `nested()` function
- possibility to override `$arr` argument value
- **UPD:** function `test()` have more than one argument (in this case, ...func_get_args() won't work)
- actually, this is simplified problem. Imagine that there are several classes that have something like `test()` method with default `$arr` parameter that calls `nested()` method of other class. I want to achieve that `nested()` method is called with default parameters when `test()` method is called with default parameters.

Is that possible?

```
<?php

function test(int $i = 0, array $arr = null)
{
  nested($arr);
}

function nested(array $arr = [1,2,3])
{
   var_dump($arr);
}

test();
test(5, [4,5,6]);
```

Comment: Check if `$arr` is NULL, and if so, call `nested();` …?

Comment: Agreed with @04FS

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing `$arr` into the nested function, you could instead pass in the actual parameters passed in using `func_get_args()` with [argument unpacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (`...`)

```
function test(array $arr = null)
{
    nested(...func_get_args());
}

function nested(array $arr = [1,2,3])
{
    var_dump($arr);
}

test();
```

If you want it to work with a more complex argument set-up, then you can look at the number of arguments passed (`func_num_args()`), in this case, check if there are less than 2 arguments and if there are, then force a call without any parameters.  You could check if `$arr` is `null` if there are more complex patterns, but this doesn't work if the users passes `null`...

```
function test(int $i = 0, array $arr = null)
{
    if ( func_num_args() < 2 )  {
        nested();
    }
    else    {
        nested($arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work if test() have more than one argument

Comment: @SergiiSmirnov - There's nothing in the question about multiple arguments. If there are more states, then you need to edit your question to include them. We can't guess what you want.

Comment: @SergiiSmirnov Sure it will.  More will be passed to `nested` but ignored.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check an array is empty or not

```
function test(array $arr = null)
{
  if (empty($arr)) {nested();}else{nested($arr);}
}

function nested(array $arr = [1,2,3])
{
   var_dump($arr);
}

test();
```

Comment: Then what about when the $arr in test() has values and he needs that value inside nested()?

Comment: I have given condition

Comment: This won't do what they are asking for in their question though. It says _"when test() is called without any argument"_ while you're checking if the argument is falsy. An empty array will evaluate as false as well, even though it would be an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need more, I've just updated the question's description